# install apk programmatically in android 8 (API 26)

Tags: android, apk

I wrote a method to install apk in all version of android and it works until android 8 . but it seems android 8 do not response to this method

```
install_apk(File file) {
        try {
            if (file.exists()) {
                String[] fileNameArray = file.getName().split(Pattern.quote("."));
                if (fileNameArray[fileNameArray.length - 1].equals("apk")) {
                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
                        Uri downloaded_apk = getFileUri(context, file);
                        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW).setDataAndType(downloaded_apk,
                                "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
                        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
                        context.startActivity(intent);
                    } else {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                        intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file),
                                "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
                        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                        context.startActivity(intent);
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

and this method for get uri on api >= 23

```
Uri getFileUri(Context context, File file) {
        return FileProvider.getUriForFile(context,
                context.getApplicationContext().getPackageName() + ".HelperClasses.GenericFileProvider"
                , file);
    }
```

Comment: Do you get an error? Is there a stacktrace? How is it failing?

Comment: I have emulator for different api and every thing is ok just before api 26

Comment: no error shown in logcat

Comment: @v.d Can you assure that  `Uri downloaded_apk = getFileUri(context, file);  Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW).setDataAndType(downloaded_apk, "application/vnd.android.package-archive"); intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION); context.startActivity(intent);` does launch the app afterwards the installation? 'Cause I've been trying and I can't find a solution, I have to manually reopen the app before the update

Comment: @Jose Jet Sure , it's working and with selected answer my problem is resolved .
if it doesn't work for you , make sure other things is ok for example read storage permission

Comment: @v.d it works perfectly! thank you

Answer (score 65, accepted):

You should be add a new permission.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES"/>
```

Comment: Thanks, working. I don't know why it is required although I am not using `ACTION_INSTALL_PACKAGE`

Comment: @Gavin Other than this permission, is there some more code is required?
I want to download .apk file from URL and install it. After adding this permission also it's not installing.

Comment: P.S. this permission is only granted to system apps.